# How to increment a number for 3 different paths while using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, graph, path, increment

I have a program that prints all the reachable paths of a graph. It contains 2 classes `GraphPath1` and `Search` . The program is given below:

Class GraphPath1:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class GraphPath1 {
    List<String> src=new ArrayList<String>();  // source node
    List<String> dest=new ArrayList<String>(); // destination node 

private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map = new HashMap();

public void addEdge(String node1, String node2){
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
        map.put(node1, adjacent);
        src.add(node1);
    }
    adjacent.add(node2);
    dest.add(node2);
}



public LinkedList<String> adjacentNodes(String last) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> adjacent = map.get(last);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return new LinkedList();
    }
    return new LinkedList<String>(adjacent);
}

}
```

Class Search:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import dfs.GraphPath1;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import dfs.LoanSystem;


public class Search {
private static final String START = "1";
private static final String END = "7";
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // this graph is directional
    GraphPath1 graph = new GraphPath1();

    graph.addEdge("1", "2");
    graph.addEdge("1", "3");
    graph.addEdge("2", "5");
    graph.addEdge("3", "4");
    graph.addEdge("4", "5");
    graph.addEdge("4", "6");
    graph.addEdge("5", "7");
    graph.addEdge("6", "7");
    //graph.addEdge("7", "1");

    /*
    List<String> s = graph.src;
    List<String> d = graph.dest;
    System.out.print(s);
    System.out.print(d);*/

    LinkedList<String> visited = new LinkedList();
    visited.add(START);
    new Search().DFS(graph, visited);

}


private void DFS(GraphPath1 graph, LinkedList<String> visited) {
LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
// examine adjacent nodes
for (String node : nodes) {
    if (visited.contains(node)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (node.equals(END)) {
        visited.add(node);
        printPath(visited);
        visited.removeLast();
        break;
    }
}



// in DFS, recursion needs to come after visiting adjacent nodes
for (String node : nodes) {
    if (visited.contains(node) || node.equals(END)) {
        continue;
    }

    visited.addLast(node);
    DFS(graph, visited);
    visited.removeLast();
}

}
/*
public List<Edge> getEdgeList (LinkedList<String> visited){
    List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    for(int i=0;i<=visited.size();i++)
        edges.add(new Edge(visited.get(i), visited.get(i+1)));

    return edges;
}
*/

private void printPath(LinkedList<String> visited) {

    ArrayList<String> sequence = new ArrayList<String>();
    {
    for (String node : visited) {
        sequence.add(node);

    }

}
    ArrayList<String> sequences = new ArrayList<String>();
    sequences.addAll(sequence);
    System.out.println(sequences);

}
}
```

The output of this program is :

```
1,2,5,7
1,3,4,5,7
1,3,4,6,7
```

Now I need to print 3 different messages for these 3 paths. For Example:

```
This is Path 1:
1,2,5,7
This is Path 2:
1,3,4,5,7
This is Path 3:
1,3,4,6,7
```

But I don't know how to do this. Can anyone give me any idea how can I increment the number I used in the message (i.e. This is Path 1:) for the 3 different paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not hard to do. All you need is a counter variable to keep track of which path you are currently printing. In your case you can set a counter to 0 before you call the `DFS()` function. Then before each print you increment it and then print your line saying which path it is. After that you call `printPath()`. This could look something like that:

```
private int pathCount = 0;

// more of you code ...

private void DFS(GraphPath1 graph, LinkedList<String> visited) {
    LinkedList<String> nodes = graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
    // examine adjacent nodes
    for (String node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node.equals(END)) {
            visited.add(node);
            pathNumber++;
            System.out.println("This is path " + pathNumber + ":");
            printPath(visited);
            visited.removeLast();
            break;
        }
    }

    // the rest of the algorithm ...
}
```

<strike>One more thing: If you make DFS a static function (`private static void DFS(...)`),  you can call it directly from the main function without having to create an instance of the Search class and `new Search().DFS(graph, visited);` can be turned into `DFS(graph, visited);`.</strike>
As we now use a instance variable to keep track of the path count, one instance of the Search class per search is what we want.

Edit: Reworked code snippet to use a instance variable instead of a local one in the function, which does not work as the function is recursive. Thanks to Andreas for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have *raw types*. DON'T!!!!
E.g. change `adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();` to `adjacent = new LinkedHashSet<>();`
If you use a good IDE, it should have already told you this.

---

Normally, you'd want the search to *return* the result, not print it, otherwise you cannot write any code that needs/uses the result.

This means that you need a result collector, and pass that in as a parameter to the recursive method. You then print result when search is complete.

Also:

- `DFS` can be made `static`.
- Handling of `END` and recursive calls can be unified.
- [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) would be a better type for `visited`.
- When doing recursive methods, it's often a good idea to isolate it behind an entry method, so caller doesn't have to know about extra parameters needed by the recursion (e.g. `visited`).
- `START` and `END` should be made parameters of `DFS`, so you can perform multiple searches on the same graph, if needed.
- Your `printPath` method seems a bit excessive.

```java
public final class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphPath1 graph = new GraphPath1();
        graph.addEdge("1", "2");
        graph.addEdge("1", "3");
        graph.addEdge("2", "5");
        graph.addEdge("3", "4");
        graph.addEdge("4", "5");
        graph.addEdge("4", "6");
        graph.addEdge("5", "7");
        graph.addEdge("6", "7");
        graph.addEdge("7", "1");

        searchAndPrint(graph, "1", "1");
        searchAndPrint(graph, "3", "2");
        searchAndPrint(graph, "1", "7");
    }

    private static void searchAndPrint(GraphPath1 graph, String start, String end) {
        List<List<String>> result = DFS(graph, start, end);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
            System.out.printf("This is Path %d: %s%n", i + 1, result.get(i));
    }

    private static List<List<String>> DFS(GraphPath1 graph, String start, String end) {
        if (start.equals(end))
            return Collections.singletonList(Collections.singletonList(start));
        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Deque<String> visited = new ArrayDeque<>();
        visited.add(start);
        DFS(graph, end, visited, result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void DFS(GraphPath1 graph, String end, Deque<String> visited, List<List<String>> result) {
        for (String node : graph.adjacentNodes(visited.getLast()))
            if (! visited.contains(node)) {
                visited.addLast(node);
                if (node.equals(end))
                    result.add(new ArrayList<>(visited)); // add copy to result
                else
                    DFS(graph, end, visited, result);
                visited.removeLast();
            }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
This is Path 1: [1]

This is Path 1: [3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2]
This is Path 2: [3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2]

This is Path 1: [1, 2, 5, 7]
This is Path 2: [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
This is Path 3: [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```